# Python SubPlot configuration

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, matplotlib-basemap

I am having lots of trouble configuring my figure in matplot for python.  Im relatively new to programming so my code is clunky and well inefficient.  Anyway, Im trying to make the subplot as large as possible (fullscreen if possible). I would like to fill up all of the gray area in the figure, but I cannot seem to be able to. Its a basic gis map showing roads and cities in western Oklahoma from shapefiles.  If anyone can help please leave me some suggestions.

Thanks!

p.s. if anyone knows how to get the city shapefiles to display names that would also be fantastic!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `rect` argument to `axes()` to set the `(left,bottom,right,top)` extent of the axes within the figure canvas. These are specified in normalized canvas units between 0 and 1.

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as pp
 fig = pp.figure()
 ax = fig.add_axes((0,0,1,1))
 ax.plot(range(10))
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the feedback! I actually found a good method from a friend with the tight_layout function!